# operation over corresponding keys of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some large python dictionaries which might look as:

```
dict1 = {2015: 5, 2017: 10, 2018; 20}
dict2 = {2015: 35, 2017: 80, 2018; 40}
```

Both dictionaries have same keys.

I want to generate the following:

```
dict3 = {2015: 7, 2017: 8, 2018: 2} #dict2 divided by dict1 for corresponding keys
```

Is there a way to achieve above without some kind of loop over keys?

Comment: Why without a `for` loop? Do you mean without a loop in general or just an want to use an alternative to `for` like `while`?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid any loop as dictionaries are large so walking through each key can be expensive.

Comment: Since you need to perform division on every value in both the dictionaries, then you probably must use a loop of some kind. Even if you avoided a loop somehow you still need to look at all the values giving you `O(n)` linear time same as the loop

Comment: This linear time was something I was hoping to avoid. Only other way probably is using multiprocessing.

Answer (score 3):

You may write a simple *dict comprehension* expression and iterate over the keys of any of the `dict` as:

```
>>> dict1 = {2015: 5, 2017: 10, 2018: 20}
>>> dict2 = {2015: 35, 2017: 80, 2018: 40}

>>> {key: dict2[key]/dict1[key] for key in dict1}
{2017: 8, 2018: 2, 2015: 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use *dict comprehension* expression to achive it.

**In Python 3**, divinding two `int` returns `float` as:

```
>>> {k:dict2[k]/dict1[k] for k in dict2}
{2017: 8.0, 2018: 2.0, 2015: 7.0}
```

In order to get `int`, you have to explicitly type-cast it like:

```
>>> {k:int(dict2[k]/dict1[k]) for k in dict2}
{2017: 8, 2018: 2, 2015: 7}
```

Where as that is not the case in **Python 2**. You may simply do:

```
>>> {k:dict2[k]/dict1[k] for k in dict2}
{2017: 8, 2018: 2, 2015: 7}
```